# Eventbrite integration with Webflow form

Tags: javascript, contact-form, eventbrite, webflow

I have a one page Webflow site:

https://bam-training-2020.webflow.io/

The site has a form at the bottom for people to register to attend a free online streaming event. We want to use the form to capture normal information like names and emails, but also physical addresses and t-shirt size to send them a welcome box with swag. We have the form integrated with google sheets and mailchimp through Zapier zaps. Everything is working smoothly...

But the client also wants to run the event through eventbrite to also use their marketing tools. I've been able to embed the "stock" eventbrite widget, but it doesn't fit with the style of the site and it completely circumvents the registration form that we need to use in order to capture all the info we need to get.

HERE'S THE QUESTION:

Is there a way to code the current, "REGISTER" button on the form to also pass through the information in the form to eventbrite? I've looked at webhooks, but I've never used one and I don't know where to start.

I'm looking to remove the eventbrite widget completely and use the information that we'll capture on the existing form to create a (free) purchase in eventbrite.

The code for the eventbrite widget is all in JS, so I can't really see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zapier supports eventbrite also as an integration just like google sheets and mail chimp.
https://zapier.com/apps/webflow/integrations/eventbrite

Comment: Thanks Manav. That's what I ended up having to do.